# how to migrate project with whole history into another bzr repository?

Tags: bazaar

I have old bazaar repository; now I want to migrate some projects with whole commit history from it into particular nodes in new repository. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply **push each project checkout to the new repository**.

Get your project1 (optional if you already have a local copy)

```
bzr branch bzr://Path/to/my/Project1
```

and then push it to the new repository.

```
bzr push bzr://Path/to/my/new/repository/particular/node/Project1
```

You can import your project inside a repository (or shared repository) where you want. I assume that's the 'nodes' you speak about ?
Push reference help:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.5/en/user-reference/push-help.html